# Windows 10 missing from Grub

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I have noticed from Ubuntu 23.04 that my Windows 10 has vanished from Grub.

Now, I have tried updating Grub and I have tried also setting os-prober to false, but no such luck. Yes, before anyone asks this is a uefi enabled motherboard, but all of this was working before but it looks like some update has removed my option and now I can't get it back.

Further, I tried installing boot repair but the install didn't work for some other reason.

So, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on.

Comment: I can't get into windows at all. It sits in a partition on the same disk. In the bios there is a fast boot setting. No updates have been applied to windows 10 for a while in any case

Comment: If UEFI install, you should be able to boot from UEFI one time boot key, often f12 but varies by vendor. If you left fast boot on, you may not have time to press that key, but "cold" boot rather than "warm" reboot should just give you time to press the correct key. Cold boot is full power down & drain all power, so system has to do a full start up rather than the fast boot.